# Why is there a type conversion when all of the variables are the same type?

Tags: c++

The warning is:

> Warning    C4244: 'argument': conversion from '__int64' to 'const unsigned int', possible loss of data

I tried to cast the variables and vectors whenever they appeared in the function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long int maxNum(vector<long long int> Vector) {
    long long int large;
    large = Vector[0];
    for (long long int index : Vector) {
        if (Vector[index] > large) { // error is for this line
            large = Vector[index];
        }
    }
    return large;
}
```

Comment: `operator[]` doesn't take `long long int`.

Comment: Note that `index` won't necessarily iterate over the values `0` to `size()-1`. It will take each value in `Vector` in order. It's odd to see that value used as an index.  It implies that `Vector` only contains indices into itself. Maybe you just meant to use `index` where you use `Vector[index]`.

Comment: If you want to store indices of the `std::vector`, better store them in a `size_t` type of variable.

Comment: Are you compiling on a 32 or 64 bit system?

Answer (score 2):

[`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) takes a `std::vector::size_type` (usually [`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)) as input, not a `long long int`.  On your system, the `size_type` is an `unsigned int`, so the compiler is warning you that `long long int` values (implemented as `__int64` on your system) will get truncated, potentially losing precision.

However, your loop is wrong to begin with.  A range-based `for` loop gives you the actual values in the `vector`, not indexes.

Try something more like this instead, then you won't get any errors:

```cpp
#include <vector>

long long int maxNum(const std::vector<long long int> &Vector) {
    if (Vector.empty()) {
        return -1; // or throw an exception...
    }
    long long int largest = Vector[0];
    for (long long int value : Vector) {
        if (value > largest) {
            largest = value;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Note, the standard C++ library has a [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm that you should use instead of a manual loop:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

long long int maxNum(const std::vector<long long int> &Vector) {
    auto largest = std::max_element(Vector.cbegin(), Vector.cend());
    if (largest == Vector.cend()) {
        return -1; // or throw an exception...
    }
    return *largest;
}
```